# tuple object has no attribute tick

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am making a game from python by looking some tutorials i am getting some errors
below is the code :

```
import pygame
import time
pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 500
pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Word Mystery!")

FPS = 60
clock = pygame,time.process_time()
run = True

while run:
  clock.tick(FPS)
    
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
      pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
      print(pos)


pygame.quit()
```

and below is the error i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/hangman/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    clock.tick(FPS)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'tick'
exit status 1
```

someone please solve this error

Answer (score 1):

The line `clock = pygame,time.process_time()` is at fault here.

In Python, the `,` operator creates tuple objects - like you're seeing in your exception.

Effectively that line is now:

`clock = (pygame, time.process_time())`

This makes the error a little easier to see.

Separately, `pygame.time` doesn't seem to have a `process_time` - see https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html - so you probably meant to use:

`clock = pygame.time.Clock()`

as the `Clock` object does have a `tick(framerate=0)` method, which you're using later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the commma:

```
clock = pygame.time.process_time()
#             ^
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pygame.time' has no attribute 'process_time'. It still doesn't work.

Correct one: clock = pygame.time.Clock()

Answer (score 0):

Replace `clock = pygame,time.process_time()` with `clock = pygame.time.Clock()` in your code and it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct code:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 500
pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Word Mystery!")

FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Corrected this line

run = True

while run:
   clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False
       if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
          pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
          print(pos)

 pygame.quit()
```